# How can I split a dataset into multiple datasets based on a column (which consists of groups) in sas

Tags: split, sas, dataset, sas-macro

For example for code looks like this:

```
data work.code;
input code_num $9. qty ;
datalines;
123456789 49
123456789 384
123456789 37
123456789 485
123456780 34
123456780 567
123456780 23
123456780 543
123456788 21
123456788 876
123456788 54
123456788 987
;
run;
```

I would like to break up this dataset into multiple datasets based on the code_num variable:

```
data code_num_1
123456789 49
123456789 384
123456789 37
123456789 485

data code_num_2
123456780 34
123456780 567
123456780 23
123456780 543
```

and etc. The amount of codes will vary in the future.

I tried applying the call execute function but cannot pass numbers through it...maybe a do loop?

Comment: Do you need to split the dataset into multiple datasets? Why?  Or is it enough to split it into multiple text files, such as CSV Files?

Comment: You can most definitely pass numbers to Call execute. Why do you need to split the data set? That's often not required in SAS unless you need to export separate files.

Comment: @Tom I would like to split the dataset in to multiple datasets because the codes are different for the variable code_name. I eventually  want to loop each dataset into a proc surveyselect procedure. Right now, running the proc surveyselect function on the entire dataset, it selects each code. I want to focus on one code for this function

Comment: @Reeza see my comment above thanks^^

Comment: Can we assume you're familiar with BY group processing and the STRATA option in PROC SURVEYSELECT to have different proportions for different strata's? Or that a WHERE statement in your PROC SURVEYSELECT would accomplish the same thing, more efficiently and easily.

Comment: thank you! @Reeza

Answer (score 2):

Adapting this answer from SASnrd, you can use a hash table:

https://sasnrd.com/sas-split-dataset-by-group/

```
data _null_;
   if(_N_ = 1) then do;
      if(0) then set code;   
                           
      dcl hash h(dataset:"code(obs=0)", multidata:'Y');   
         h.definekey(all:'Y');                                     
         h.definedata(all:'Y');                                    
      h.definedone();                                           
   end;

   do until(last.code_num);                                     
      set code;                                             
      by code_num;
      h.add();                                                  
   end;

   id+1;
   out = cats('code_num_', id);

   h.output(dataset:out);                                   
   h.clear();                                                   
run;
```

The only difference is that we're creating a unique ID for each dataset name rather than using the by-group. Be sure that `code_num` is sorted in some logical order. You can use `proc sort` first or the `notsorted` option if it's always in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

No need to split the dataset to work with part of the data. Just use a WHERE statement.

```
proc surveyselect data=code ..... ;
  where code_num = "123456789";
  ...
run;
```

If the data is sorted (or indexed) you can frequently just use a BY statement to treat each group separately.

```
proc surveyselect data=code ..... ;
  by code_num ;
  ...
run;
```